# Parse soap xml response to java Object

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, cxf

Is it possible to parse an XML soap response to a java Object?

I have a class generated by Apache CXF with the structure of the object, and I have the XML soap response from the request.

I want to pass the XML soap response without invoking the service to the java object.
It's possible to do this because I see in the java object create by CXF XML annotations:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(output);
Results rs = (Results) JAXBContext.newInstance(Results.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(sr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I was using Apache CXF 3.10 ,and the answer to my question is, yes it's possible to do it.  When you create the client from the command `wsdl2java` java classes are generated containing the XML annotation to do that.

The code post in the question working for that, toy can put the WSDL and send a request and take the response and save as a file and pass that to the `JAXBContext`.

Or if the owner of the web service give to you a response example you can use that too.